# Note-taking software with password protection

Tags: web-apps, note-taking, privacy

I'm looking for a note taking app that:

- Is web based so I can use it with a browser mostly in both a phone and in a PC
- Can search through the note contents or at least the titles or tags
- Asks for a password everytime you want to read a specific note or group of notes or access the whole app itself. Any of this options is okay! What I want to accomplish is that if I borrow my phone/PC to someone, they can't read my notes without knowing the password, like one can easily do with Google Keep and Microsoft OneNote in a logged in device.
- It is not Microsoft OneNote
- Optional: Logs itself out when idle for some minutes or requires the password again to access a recently opened note after some minutes of being idle

Why not OneNote: Its webapp is too slow to use, it sometimes fails to load a note, (I guess it is because it has a lot of tools to load and that I am using my password protected sections through their webapp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://crypt.ee/
Beside login and password, it also has a encryption key.
It's entirely web-based, so it doesn't have a mobile version. On mobile, you'll have to access it with a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

[RoboForm](https://www.roboform.com/) is a windows program that is engineered for password management, but also has a feature known as SafeNotes.

If the Synch feature is activated, you have access to your notes (and passwords) via web site, but also via an app on a computer or telephone.

The search option is limited to folder names, not the contents within.

The SafeNotes allows for categorizing your notes in folders (not nested), but that's about the maximum sophistication for the note taking feature.

It is not OneNote.

In order to use RoboForm, one must sign into the account. The expiration time for the sign-out is adjustable, covering your "optional" request.